# Current Navigation does not display what I'm looking for!

Tags: 2010, navigation, sub-site

I activated the Current Navigation option

> Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site,
>   and the current site's siblings

but I'm not getting what I'm expecting to. I mean that some of the items are shown and some are not. I changed the parameter

> Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site,
>   and the current site's siblings

[image]

from 20 to 50 and I haven't saw changes.

However, when I cahnged the setting to

> Display only the navigation items below the current site

[image]

I was able to have all the subsites as opposed to the previous setting.

Any clues with that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick launch (or current navigation) in out-of-the-box SharePoint 2010 lets you show two tiers, which show up as **headings** (tier 1) and **links** under those headings (tier 2).

When you set the current navigation to:

> Display only the navigation items below the current site

...It shows each "heading" from the current site's navigation as a tier 1 **heading**, and each "link" from the current site's navigation as a tier 2 **link**.

So far, so good; a heading is a heading and a link is a link.

However, when you set the current navigation to:

> Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site, and the current site's siblings

...It will instead show each **site**--including the current site and any sibling sites--as a tier 1 **heading**, and it will show each "heading" from the current site's navigation as a tier 2 **link**.

*This means that your headings are essentially being demoted to links!*

Since the current navigation only has room for two tiers, there's no place left for the "links" from the current navigation... it won't add "tier 3" links below your others.

Showing the sibling sites can be nice-- it achieves a basic "accordion" like navigation effect, where you can switch between sites at the same level very easily-- but the downside is that it limits your options with respect to headings/subheadings on the quick launch.